# Join by a prefix, similar to SQL's ON ... LIKE

Tags: sql, r, join

How does one perform a join/merge using a prefix (of varying length) of a column as a key? I am trying to translate the following SQL code:

```
SELECT a.person_id, a.tn_code, b.list_id
FROM tblA a
INNER JOIN tblB b
ON tn_code LIKE TnCode + "%"
```

tblA

```
person_id  tn_code
        1    C18.4
        2  M8820/9
        3     X20.
...
```

tblB

```
ListID TnCode
  1.01   A0.1
  1.01   A0.2
...
```

I have ideas such as preparing a new key `TnCode_prefix = gsub("^(.*)\\.(.*)$", "\\1", TnCode)` and then joining on the new column, or using `data.table`'s rolling join, but they are only approximate translations? Is there an exact equivalent in R?

I am aware of using `sqldf` and simply passing the original SQL statement to `sqldf`, but I'm wondering if there is another way.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is not a direct translation. If you memory can take it, I think the easiest solution is a full join and then filter the rows  that don't meet your criteria

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a prefix on the fly and joining on that? I used `dplyr` to create the prefix and do the join.

```
library(dplyr)

# Fake Data
set.seed(1093)
tblA = data.frame(person_id=sample(1:10, 50, replace=TRUE),
                  tn_code = paste0(sample(paste0(paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:3],3),c(40:42,401:403,421:423))), 50, replace=TRUE),
                                   ".", sample(160:170, 50, replace=TRUE)))
tblB = data.frame(ListID=paste0(sample(1:10, 50, replace=TRUE),".",
                                sample(10:20, 50, replace=TRUE)),
                  TnCode = paste0(sample(paste0(paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:3],3),c(40:42,401:403,421:423))), 50, replace=TRUE),
                                  ".", sample(160:170, 50, replace=TRUE)))

# Join on first letter of tn_code and TnCode
newTbl = tblA %>% mutate(join_prefix=gsub("(.*)\\..*", "\\1", tn_code)) %>%
  left_join(tblB %>% mutate(join_prefix=gsub("(.*)\\..*", "\\1", TnCode)),
            by="join_prefix")
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood, but it's helped me. The issue is that the length of the prefix may be different for each row, so a regular expression will either have false positives or false negatives. For example, `T801.1` should match `T80`, **but not** if `T801` exists. That is, the prefix should be maximal.

Comment: Just started messing around with it, but haven't finished yet. I'll see what I can come up with tomorrow.